# Confused how to revert all files as per master branch

Tags: git

I created a new branch (`git branch working`) and then switched to that branch (`git checkout working`). I then added some new files/folders and edited some existing files.

Now I want to get back to how things were before creating the 'working' branch. ie: I want to remove the new files/folders that were added, and undo any changes that were made to existing files.

I simply checked out master (`checkout master`) but nothing reverted back to how it was. Im obviously misunderstanding something here. If I do a `git status` while on the 'master' branch I get:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
      Here are the existing files I edited

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
      Here are the new files/folders I added
```

I thought by checking out master, everything would revert back to before I created the 'working' branch. What do I need to do at this point?

Also, once i've reverted everything back to how it was in master,...what if I wanted to checkout 'working' again. Would all the new files/folders and changes be there still? (ie: swap between master / working as needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I need to do at this point?

You need to checkout working branch, add your changes there and commit them. Then they are 'registered' to that branch.

After that you can checkout master and it will be in the original state without the changes.

It does not work currently because you have not committed the changes, and changes in the working directory are not discarded when changing branches so they are brought back over the master branch during checkout.

> Also, once i've reverted everything back to how it was in master,...what if I wanted to checkout 'working' again. Would all the new files/folders and changes be there still?

Yes, because the commit with the changes is on the working branch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -df
```

to reset to HEAD.

No, if you do this, these files won't be in working.

If you want to do that, then commit the files to working. Or use git add untrack files. And then:

```
git stash
```

Later you can go to master, then come back to working, do this:

```
git stash pop
```

You shouldn't worry about new files and folders if they are untrack. You anyway need to add them. If you haven't added then you can go to master without any effect and come back to working. They will remain untracked.

But it's better to commit to working. Then your changes are always there for the branch where you committed . If you don't want to commit, then use stash approach.